# Does the mark all as read button trigger a read receipt in Outlook 2010?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

This relates to Outlook 2010. I would like to know if a read receipt is sent if all you do is click on the "Mark all as read" button but don't actually open the email messages. What if you then go back and open a message? I know a new read message is not sent every time I open a previously read message so I am wondering if no receipt would ever be sent back to the sender.

Answer (score 2):

Having just tested this, marking all as read does not trigger the receipt request.

Answer (score 0):

Having just tested this, my version of Outlook 2010 does send a read receipt when mail is simply marked as read.

It is likely connected with whether you allow read receipt acknowledgement or not.